# Hiding individual sections from ToC in a modular document

Tags: table-of-contents, multiple-files

I'm working on a modular thesis using the `amsbook` package and I would like to hide specific sections from the table of contents. None of the solutions for single files I found seem to work in the modular case. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by modular here? You have given very few clues about your document. Splitting the source into multiple files typically does not affect the tex processing at all, `\input` just works (more or less) as if the file contents were copied in at that point.